# How to prevent an Event Hub consumer from disconnecting from the producer?

Tags: kotlin, azure-eventhub

We have a scenario where external systems generate events that are sent to an EventHub. Additionally, we have a separate service that consumes data from the EventHub. However, if the producer stops sending events to a partition, the consumer eventually disconnects from it. What can be done to ensure that the consumer remains connected to the producer? Furthermore, I require the capability to switch between consuming events from the beginning or the latest point.

My second question is: From a consumer's perspective, what are the differences between the EventProcessorClient and EventHubClient?

This is my consumer code.

```
        val retryOptions = AmqpRetryOptions()
            .setDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .setMaxDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
            .setMaxRetries(3)
            .setMode(AmqpRetryMode.EXPONENTIAL)

        val eventHubClientBuilder = EventHubClientBuilder()
            .connectionString("connectionString")
            .consumerGroup(EventHubClientBuilder.DEFAULT_CONSUMER_GROUP_NAME)
            .retryOptions(retryOptions)
            .transportType(AmqpTransportType.AMQP_WEB_SOCKETS)
        val eventHubClient = eventHubClientBuilder.buildAsyncConsumerClient()

        // this boolean indicates whether to read from the beginning of the stream
        eventHubClient.receive(true)
            .subscribe {
                log.info(
                    "Data Offset: ${it.data.offset}, " +
                        "Sequence number: ${it.data.sequenceNumber}, " +
                        "PartitionId: ${it.partitionContext.partitionId}, " +
                        "Enqueued time: ${it.data.enqueuedTime}, " +
                        "Received message: ${it.data.bodyAsString}"
                )
                // process messages
            }
```

After a certain period of time, the consumer's logs display the following information:

`{"az.sdk.message":"Unable to schedule close work. Closing manually." ... }`

`{"az.sdk.message":"ReactorDispatcher instance is closed. Should not continue dispatching work to this reactor.","exception":"ReactorDispatcher instance is closed. Should not continue dispatching work to this reactor." ...}`

`{"az.sdk.message":"Timed out waiting for RequestResponseChannel to complete closing. Manually closing." ...}`

Answer (score 0):

> To prevent an Event Hub consumer from disconnecting from the producer.

The producer has to keep on sending events to the Event Hub's partitions. If the producer stops sending events to a partition, then the consumer disconnects as there is no new data to consume.

Steps to maintain the connection between the producer and the consumer.

- Check if there are any issues with the producer that might cause it to stop sending events.
- Check the producer is running correctly and can continuously send events to the Event Hub.
- Monitor the producer's activity
- Implement a failover mechanism in case the primary producer fails or stops sending events.

When creating the consumer group for the consumer, make sure you configure the appropriate settings. Like, setting the `EventPosition` to `EventPosition.fromStartOfStream()` if you want the consumer to read from the beginning of the `event stream`, or use `EventPosition.latest()` to read only the latest events.

Code reference taken from  [Azure Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host)

```
 string conn = @"Connection";
     string hub = "myhub";
     int NoOfEvents = 10;
   await using (var pc = new EventHubProducerClient(conn, hub))
    {
        EventDataBatch event_Batch = await pc.CreateBatchAsync();

        for (int i = 1; i <= NoOfEvents; i++)
        {
            string msg = $"Event {i}";
            event_Batch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg)));
        }

        await pc.SendAsync(event_Batch);
        Console.WriteLine($"Sent {NoOfEvents} events to hub: {hub}");
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Metrics in Azure.

[image]

> Regarding the differences between EventProcessorClient and EventHubClient.

**EventProcessorClient**
This provides a higher-level abstraction for event processing. It allows consume events from an Event Hub by providing built-in features like load balancing, checkpointing and automatic partition management.

And is designed to handle the process events in parallel from multiple partitions and ensure fault tolerance.

**EventHubClient**

This provides a lower-level API for consuming events from an Event Hub. And have more control over event consumption but requires you to handle partition management, load balancing, and checkpointing manually.

And is suitable to consume events from a single partition.

And also refer to [Exchange events using different protocols.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-exchange-events-different-protocols)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think we managed to send and receive events but the producer is used once per week to send a batch of events. After that batch the connection remains open until it closes by itself. The original question was, how to prevent the closing? I do not want to just send empty events to keep connection open. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: You can make use of the Keep-Alive feature in the underlying AMQP protocol.

By default, the Event Hub client library sets the idle timeout for the connection to 1 minute. This means that if there is no activity (no events being sent or received) on the connection for 1 minute, the connection will be automatically closed. To prevent the connection from closing, you can increase the idle timeout value by setting the TransportOptions.idleTimeout

Comment: I was able to locate the feature in the C# SDK, but I'm currently using the Java SDK and haven't found a way to configure it in the Java SDK.

Comment: One solution is to periodically send a low-volume heartbeat event to the Event Hub. This can be a simple event with minimal payload that is sent at regular intervals to keep the connection active.


Check [Java SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send?tabs=passwordless,roles-azure-portal) for more information.

Comment: I believe I understand your message. Essentially, you are suggesting that the consumer sends an event back to the Event Hub. Am I correct in understanding that the consumer will then read the event once more? It would be preferable if we could avoid making any modifications to the producer, as we have no control over it.

Comment: It is important to be aware that there are two idle timeouts - one on the client that you can configure, as Rajesh indicated.  The other is on the service; after 20 minutes idle, Event Hubs will force-close the connection.  The client would need to perform a service operation to trigger the connection being recreated.

Comment: The bigger question is - why do you want to keep the connection open?  Using the synchronous client in Java would allow you to poll on a timer and would recreate connections as needed.  Using the processor would be the recommended approach, as it will self-manage and keep reading whether events are present or not.

Comment: @JesseSquire Is there an alternative approach for responding to new messages in EventHub in real-time? I'm looking for a way to instantly react to each event as it is sent to EventHub, rather than waiting for my consumer to recreate the connection after a certain period of time. I may have misunderstood the concept of EventHub, but I believed it would function similarly to Kafka, where this behavior is considered normal and acceptable.

Comment: As mentioned, either using the processor or polling the sync client in a loop would trigger service operations regularly and keep the service from hitting an idle timeout.